# Redirect to a controller action, action not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5.

My objective is to redirect to another method on the same controller to display a view with data.

```
class SeancesController extends Controller {

     ...

     public function getRecommandations(Request $request) {

          ...

          $data = [
               'recommandationAutresActiviteMemeDateHeure' => $recommandationAutresActiviteMemeDateHeure,
               'recommandationsMemeActiviteMemeHeure'      => $recommandationsMemeActiviteMemeHeure,
               'recommandationsMemeActiviteMemeDate'       => $recommandationsMemeActiviteMemeDate
          ];

          return redirect()->action('SeancesController@showRecommandations', $data);
     }

     public function showRecommandations(Request $request) {
          return view('listeRecommandations', $request->data);
     }
}
```

It is the right way to do this? Because I get this error :

> InvalidArgumentException: Action App\Http\Controllers\SeancesController@showRecommandations not defined. in file /home/nicolas/public_html/M1_CSI/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 338

I need to use `action` because I use an ajax call to access at `getRecommandations()`.

I used this doc : http://laraveldaily.com/all-about-redirects-in-laravel-5/.

I didn't add a route that points to `showRecommendations` on my routing file. It's a problem?

Thank's for help!

Comment: Do you have a route calling that exact method? You probably need to have a route like `Route::get('foobar', 'SeancesController@showRecommandations');` for it to work.

Comment: The method `showRecommandations()`? No I don't have define route.

Comment: @Marwelln but with what I replace `foobar` because this route is not called via the urls.

Comment: why you use redirect() ? you can simple call $this->showRecommandations($request);  - but calling another method just for return view is not a good practice

Comment: Because I'm using ajax and if I'm not using redirect() the view is return to the ajax call ... I hope I'm prettry clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't add a route that points to showRecommendations on my routing file. It's a problem?

yes , it is a problem. because the redirector checks the routes that are assigned to the action and redirects the user to the route.

Comment: Ok but if I define a route, we can access from anywhere on this page. I want to access on this page only after accessing `getRecommendations()`.

Comment: you can just return the $this->showRecommandations($data) and change the argument of this method to data instead of request .

Comment: And juste with that, URL is not accessible with the URL?

Comment: When I'm doing this, I got an error : `Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\SeancesController::showRecommandations()`.

Comment: I solved the problem, that's why I accept your answer. Thanks a lot!